# zoom on video html5 to prevent letterbox black sides on fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

there is a way in JS of HTML5 to zoom on a video in a html5 page, to prevent letterbox black sides when in  fullscreen mode?

Comment: I believe the technique is called "Overscan". You would set the smallest dimension of the video to the largest dimension of the window, and let it otherwise preserve aspect ratio. You will be cutting off content from the user, though.

Comment: You get black sides, OR stretch OR cut-off content. Choose one.

Answer (score 0):

check out this...https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/zooming-and-rotating-for-video-in-html5-and-css3/

zooming the element maybe you can do something that help you...